# Open source richtext control for .Net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

Is there any good richtextcontrol for .net forms i tried almost all extended richtextcontrols from several websites but there is no print like view for any control, i want to add deference system in my app but there is no free control available and controls like from http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor/ 
are very expensive for a student. iam searching from last two months but find no results and tried hard to make my own control but found no idea to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use Visual Studio RichTextBox built in control.

If that is not enough then use ICSharpCode.TextEditor.dll from [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)

This TextEditor is very good for syntaxt highlighting feature.

Example to use please follow:
[Using ICSharpCode.TextEditor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor)

Regards

Comment: Thanks, for examples i already seen that. iam making a RichTextEditor like wordpad in Windows 7 with some extra dictionary features so i need  control like wordpad,if their is any control for this purpose?

Comment: if there is any way to use openofice text control in vb.net?